# PyNaCl doesn't want to install during PyGithub instalation(wheel building doesn't finish)

Tags: pip, pynacl, pep517

I have already tried:

- running the command as sudo (as you can see)
- downgrading pip
- installing make and other build-essential
- installing pynacl alone
- installing it without using PEP 517 (it didn't install, just output an error that it needs PEP 517)

Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (server)
Python3 version is 3.6.9
pip is in the latest version (21.1 if I am correct)
I am doing everything through Webmin 1.973

I reran with the command "sudo pip3 install pynacl --log "
Link to the log: [log on the pastebin.pl](https://pastebin.pl/view/bfda589d)

```
> sudo pip3 install  pynacl
WARNING: Value for scheme.platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
sysconfig: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WARNING: Value for scheme.purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
sysconfig: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /usr/local/include/python3.6/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /usr/include/python3.6m
WARNING: Value for scheme.scripts does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /usr/local/bin
sysconfig: /usr/bin
WARNING: Value for scheme.data does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /usr/local
sysconfig: /usr
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Collecting pynacl
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.4.0.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  WARNING: Value for purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
  distutils: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
  WARNING: Value for platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
  distutils: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1
  Using cached cffi-1.14.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_i686.whl (378 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pynacl) (1.11.0)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pynacl
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: Please post the complete error log. Use a pastebin-like service  if the log doesn’t fit in the answer.

Comment: Ok. I'll do what you said. Yeah. It didn't fit when I first tried.

Comment: Done. Now you have your log.

Comment: `fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory` indicates you haven't install Python header files. If you have a Debian or its derivative (Ubuntu and friends), the essential command is `apt install python-dev` (or `python3-dev`), for RHEL derivatives it's `yum install python3-devel`.

Comment: Successfully built pynacl
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, pynacl
Successfully installed cffi-1.14.5 pycparser-2.20 pynacl-1.4.0
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Yep. It did the job. Thanks. Really thank tou. Add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)