# Can not install gwpy package with python 3.9 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install the [gwpy](https://github.com/gwpy/gwpy) package in Ubuntu 20.04 and with Python 3.9

##### While successfully installed with below command for python 3.8 but can not make it work for Python 3.9

```
pip3 install gwpy
```

The above command successfully installs `gwpy` in directory `/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and working good with Python 3.8

#### But when I am choosing Python 3.9 then `gwpy` module is not getting recognized and getting "ImportError: No module named gwpy"

Have tried below command for Python 3.9

```
python3.9 -m pip install
```

and also,

```
pip3.9 install gwpy
```

But get the same error (below)

( I already uninstalled and re-installed ligo-segments )

```
Building wheels for collected packages: ligo-segments
  Building wheel for ligo-segments (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-m3l2cb3f
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/
  Complete output (20 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo
  copying ligo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
  copying ligo/segments/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
  copying ligo/segments/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
  running build_ext
  building 'ligo.segments.__segments' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/infinity.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/infinity.o
  src/infinity.c:29:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     29 | #include <Python.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ligo-segments
  Running setup.py clean for ligo-segments
Failed to build ligo-segments
Installing collected packages: ligo-segments, pyerfa, gwdatafind, tqdm, ligotimegps, h5py, gwosc, dqsegdb2, astropy, gwpy
    Running setup.py install for ligo-segments ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7g5qg2rc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/paul/.local/include/python3.9/ligo-segments
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo
    copying ligo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
    copying ligo/segments/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
    copying ligo/segments/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/ligo/segments
    running build_ext
    building 'ligo.segments.__segments' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/infinity.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/infinity.o
    src/infinity.c:29:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include <Python.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l_etxqfg/ligo-segments_093d6d7361fe403dba837e6e5793581f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7g5qg2rc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/paul/.local/include/python3.9/ligo-segments Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have already removed Python 3.9 completely and freshly re-installed it in my system.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks a ton @Sujay - that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from the very helpful comment of @Sujay at the bottom of the question.

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077790/1902852)

Just installed below

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```