# /usr/bin/python3: No module named python3-devel

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, cygwin

I'm on Windows 10 and I've installed python3-devel through Cygwin package manager (essentially I was following the answer **Solution for Cygwin** in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory) thread). But when I wanted to confirm if the module was installed using `python3 -m python3-devel --version`, the output was `/usr/bin/python3: No module named python3-devel`.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue or what I could do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a package is installed in Cygwin use `cygcheck`

```
$ cygcheck -c python38-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python38-devel       3.8.10-1       OK

$ cygcheck -l python38-devel
/etc/postinstall/python38-devel.sh
/etc/preremove/python38-devel.sh
/usr/bin/2to3-3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/include/python3.8/abstract.h
/usr/include/python3.8/asdl.h
/usr/include/python3.8/ast.h
...
/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-cygwin/Setup
/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-cygwin/Setup.local
/usr/lib/libpython3.8.dll.a
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.8.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.8-embed.pc
```

python3-devel will pull python38-devel

```
$ cygcheck-dep -qr python3-devel
 python3-devel: requires ( python3 python38-devel )
```

Comment: python3-devel is a cygwin package, not a python package. It is required to embed python in a C program, or to build binary plugins for python3. It is not required to run python scripts nor to develop pure python packages.

Comment: Apparently, installing python3-devel was the problem - how and why did that happen is another question. Anyway, the command matzeri wrote has shown there is nothing installed, so I will mark it as the answer.