# Terminal Error installing pickle5 on linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to install the package pickle5 on linux using the command
`pip3 install --user pickle5`
but when I do I get the error

```
pickle5/compat.h:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and I cannot figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your distro, you need to install this before:

For apt (Ubuntu, Debian...):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev   # for python2.x installs
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3.x installs
```

For yum (CentOS, RHEL...):

```
sudo yum install python-devel    # for python2.x installs
sudo yum install python3-devel   # for python3.x installs
```

Then it should work.

You have more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory/21530768)