# failed to installing package webrtcvad in ubuntu

Tags: python, installation, setup.py

Using pip 22.0.4 to install webrtcvad fails with

```
pip3 install webrtcvad
```

output:

```
Collecting webrtcvad
  Using cached webrtcvad-2.0.10.tar.gz (66 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: webrtcvad
  Building wheel for webrtcvad (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      copying webrtcvad.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      running build_ext
      building '_webrtcvad' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DWEBRTC_POSIX -Icbits -I/media/botika/DATA-2/Dhea/dhea_env/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c cbits/pywebrtcvad.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o
      cbits/pywebrtcvad.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for webrtcvad
  Running setup.py clean for webrtcvad
Failed to build webrtcvad
Installing collected packages: webrtcvad
  Running setup.py install for webrtcvad ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for webrtcvad did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      copying webrtcvad.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      running build_ext
      building '_webrtcvad' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DWEBRTC_POSIX -Icbits -I/media/botika/DATA-2/Dhea/dhea_env/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c cbits/pywebrtcvad.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/cbits/pywebrtcvad.o
      cbits/pywebrtcvad.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> webrtcvad

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the Python headers. You can install them with this command:

```
#Replace the 3.10 in the below command with your Python version before running.
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev libpython3.10-dev
```

Comment: I've tried using 'sudo apt-get install python3-dev', but still error

Comment: @cupcakes I changed 3.10 to 3.7 and it worked in my case

Comment: Worked for me when I replaced 3.10 to 3.9.

Comment: You have to install the `-dev` version accordingly to the python version you are using.

`python 3.9.14` for example will require `python3.9-dev`