# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory when compiling pybind11 example

Tags: python, pybind11

I am starting out with `pybind11`, trying to compile the first example.  I am using Xubuntu 20.04.  My system python is 3.8, but I have install `pybind11` only for python 3.10, which is the version that executes when I type `python` at the command prompt.  When I run the compilation command given in the `pybind11` docs:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3.10 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3.10-config --extension-suffix)
```

I get the error message:

```
     fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  213 | #include <Python.h>
```

I followed the advice give in the accepted answer to [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory), and ran

```
sudo apt install python3.10-dev
```

but this had no effect, even though `Python.h` now exists in `/usr/include/python3.10`.
I should perhaps mention that I am not using a virtual environment at this point.

**EDIT**

```
python3.10-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g   -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall
```

**EDIT**

I changed the command as suggested by 9769953:

```
Pybind11Test$ c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3.10 -m pybind11 python3.10-config --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3.10-config --extension-suffix)
usage: __main__.py [-h] [--includes] [--cmakedir]
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: python3.10-config
example.cpp:1:10: fatal error: pybind11/pybind11.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Adding `python3.10-config` gave me an `unrecognized argumnents` error, but the compilation failed at a different place.  `#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>` is the first line of `example.cpp`.

The file exists at

```
/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h
```

**EDIT**

Latest attempt

```
Pybind11Test$ c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3.10 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example.out
In file included from /home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../cast.h:13,
                 from /home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:13,
                 from /home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                 from /home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h:213:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  213 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the OS installs the header files for Python 3.10 in `/usr/include/python3.10/include`. This keeps them separate from the default sytem Python (3.8), in case that development package is also installed (otherwise, one set of files would overwrite the other set of files).

But `/usr/include/python3.10/include` is not in the default search path for includes for the C++ compiler; you have to add it. You could do that manually, but the `python-config` tool takes (better) care of that normally. Add

```
python3.10-config --includes
```

as a subshell command (`$(...)`) to the command line. Similar to what pybind does, with `$(python -m pybind --includes)` to let the compiler find pybind's include files.
Obviously, the correct `python-config` variant needs to be used, hence `python3.10-config`.

The shared library files are fewer, and named by having the Python version in their filename, so these can all live safely together in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. You'll find `libpython3.8.so` and `libpython3.10.so` next to each other in that directory. So there is no need to add the library search path (that option doesn't even exist for `python-config`, but it is included in `python3.10-config --ldflags`).

All in all, the command would then look like:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC \
$(python3.10-config --includes) \
$(python3.10 -m pybind11 --includes) \
-o example$(python3.10-config --extension-suffix) \
example.cpp
```

(broken across a few lines for readability.)