# note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure

Tags: python, docker, requirements.txt

so i am trying to run my dad's project after him passing away but i am having a problem installing the requirements.txt

```
      DEPRECATION: typed-ast is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for typed-ast ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for typed-ast did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/samerdaghestani/Downloads/python/ipython/project 2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/typed_ast
      copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/typed_ast
      running build_ext
      building '_ast27' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27/Custom
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27/Parser
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27/Python
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Iast27/Include "-I/Users/samerdaghestani/Downloads/python/ipython/project 2/venv/include" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Iast27/Include "-I/Users/samerdaghestani/Downloads/python/ipython/project 2/venv/include" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/ast27/Parser/acceler.o
      ast27/Parser/acceler.c:13:10: fatal error: 'pgenheaders.h' file not found
      #include "pgenheaders.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> typed-ast

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

there is a really basic document which says to run the file below to install the requirements

```
-r ./base.txt

Werkzeug==0.14.1  # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug
ipdb==0.11  # https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb
Sphinx==1.8.3  # https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1  # https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2

# Testing
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mypy==0.650  # https://github.com/python/mypy
pytest==4.0.2  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
pytest-sugar==0.9.2  # https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar

# Code quality
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flake8==3.6.0  # https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
coverage==4.5.2  # https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy

# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
factory-boy==2.11.1  # https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy

django-debug-toolbar==1.11  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar
django-extensions==2.1.4  # https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
django-coverage-plugin==1.6.0  # https://github.com/nedbat/django_coverage_plugin
pytest-django==3.4.4  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django
```

it is linked to another requirements file which is called base.txt i will provide the code below

```
pytz==2018.7  # https://github.com/stub42/pytz
python-slugify==2.0.0  # https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify
Pillow==5.3.0  # https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow
argon2-cffi==18.3.0  # https://github.com/hynek/argon2_cffi
redis>=2.10.6, < 3  # pyup: < 3 # https://github.com/antirez/redis
celery==4.2.1  # pyup: < 5.0  # https://github.com/celery/celery

# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
django==2.0.9  # pyup: < 2.1  # https://www.djangoproject.com/
django-environ==0.4.5  # https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ
django-model-utils==3.1.2  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils
django-allauth==0.38.0  # https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2  # https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms
django-redis==4.10.0  # https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis

# Django REST Framework
djangorestframework==3.9.0  # https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework
coreapi==2.3.3  # https://github.com/core-api/python-client

django-datatables-view==1.17.0
```

for now i created a virtualenv with python 3.8 and tried to install the requirements

Comment: Sorry for your loss. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/609290). You'll need the headers included in `python-dev` to overcome that error.