# Not possible to install Biopython in Thonny

Tags: python, ide, biopython, thonny

i get a Error message when installing Biopython in Thonny. Can someone help me please? :)

```
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c Bio/Align/_aligners.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/Bio/Align/_aligners.o
      Bio/Align/_aligners.c:11:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> biopython

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
Process returned with code 1
```

I already tried to install Biopython manuel in the bash terminal, but it also did not work. This message occurs:

```
pip install Biopython
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I also already reinstalled Thonny, but it did not help.

**EDITED**

Thonny
Python IDE for beginners

could be find here : https://thonny.org/

Comment: What happens when you type `python` in a `bash` terminal? Also, welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Please specify wich version of tonny are you using : Windows






 •  Mac




 •  Linux

Comment: from the IDE project home webpage : Simple and clean pip GUI. Select Tools → Manage packages for even easier installation of 3rd party packages.

Comment: note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Comment: @MarceloPaco. Thonny comes with Python 3.10 built in,

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/thonny

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory ---> Python including development header files like python.h, which on Linux are often not installed by default (trying looking for and installing a package named python-dev or python-devel as well as the python package).

Comment: https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/760 Can't install package (gcc error) on clean install