# Python.h: No such file or directory when installing a package

Tags: python, package, sudo

I installed various packages in my environment, however now I am trying to install qubovert package on an external cluster I have access to, but I am getting this error

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I./qubovert/sim/src/ -I/users/ecamilleri/downloads/python3100/Python-3.10.0/v3100_venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c ./qubovert/sim/_canneal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/./qubovert/sim/_canneal.o
./qubovert/sim/_canneal.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
```

I found one can install the following

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev
```

but I do not have sudo rights.

Is there another way I can install the package or the related dev environment?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209335/564341

Comment: Related: [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21530577/11082165)