# Error Installing Numpy: "Cannot compile `Python.h`" Windows

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I wanted to work on a project involving NBA statistics in Python, so I went to download nba_api:
`pip install nba_api`

Now, I am not very knowledgeable about the inner-workings or more technical side of Python, but in trying to install the api I wound up going down a rabbit hole of having to download stuff like ninja, cmake, and Visual Studio trying to get this thing to work. I'm at the point now where my current error is in downloading numpy, which I had installed before and aren't too sure how I managed to uninstall it. But anyway..

Again, I'm not too technically inclined and don't really know what information would be the most useful in helping solve this, so if I leave out important information let me know. I am running code on stock Windows 10, Python 3.10, and am pasting the cmd logs below. A lot of solutions I've seen use linux and are able to download python-dev or python-devel, but I haven't been able to find anything that works on windows. I've also seen some people say conda makes downloading Python packages, but I don't know too much about that and wondering if that would solve my problem.

Sorry I seem so noobish I just wanted to get this api to work lol

```
C:\Users\garrett>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.3.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      + C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\python3.exe C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856 C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856\.mesonpy-fedvcrzu\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856\.mesonpy-fedvcrzu\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.99
      Source dir: C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856
      Build dir: C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856\.mesonpy-fedvcrzu\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: NumPy
      Project version: 1.26.3
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 13.1.0 "cc (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.40
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 13.1.0 "c++ (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.40
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.8)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\python3.exe)
      Found pkg-config: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\pkg-config.EXE (1.8.0)
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.10
      Has header "Python.h" with dependency python-3.10: NO

      ..\..\meson.build:44:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: Cannot compile `Python.h`. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r_x_gboo\numpy_694cf39dff9d434a8c4ce95a0928a856\.mesonpy-fedvcrzu\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Looks like a `meson` problem with `numpy`. Are you open to work on any other idle not using meson?

Comment: Some links not sure if they are related: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/12547; https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/pull/12586; https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25518; https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24317

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983458/1467914

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I got everything to work simply getting a clean install of python and installing numpy and the api that way. I will say meson did appear to be the problem, as when I tried installing an older version of numpy that didn't rely on meson to build there was a different error message. Also I got cygwin working and while that didn't help me with this specific problem I'm sure having python-dev installed will prove helpful at some point. Thank you for your help.