# How to get PIP for python

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip.py. Whenever I search for the installer, it opens to a new tab with codes in it, with nothing that I can download. What am I meant to do, am I meant to copy-paste the code into the Python interpreter? How can I get it to work for the Windows 7 32bit version?

Comment: check this, it works on every platform : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3/33964956#33964956

Comment: in one command: python2 `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io./pip/2.7/get-pip.py | python` or python3 `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io./get-pip.py | python3`

Comment: "bootstrap.pypa.io. " why you adding . after io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these binaries to install `pip` or any other packages of your interest.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip

Answer (score 10):

**Installing with source**

Go to this link: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Copy the contents of this file onto another new file and save it as get-pip.py (when it asks you what you want to do with the file, click Save, then copy the contents of the file onto another new file), and open your Windows Command Prompt as an admin and go to the file path and then enter (you need Internet for this) the following command,

```
python get-pip.py install
```

**For help on installing with different operating systems**

Refer to this link: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

**Installing with an exe file**

Click [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) to get the file, and install it and you need to set a path to the pip directory, you will find a source folder in the C drive and you can find the pip file, then set the folder path.

Comment: how can i install with no internet connection to linux box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this guide to install the latest version of Python, PIP and virtualenv for any platform. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/