# Kivy Buildozer - "No module named setuptools" after installing setuptools

Tags: android, python, flask, kivy, buildozer

I have a Flask server in a Python file. It's really simple:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm using Kivy's Buildozer to build my file. After creating `buildozer.spec` and specifying `requirements = kivy,flask` I try to build with `buildozer -v android debug` which should build the APK.

Instead, it crashes in the middle of building and gives me this error:

> File "setup.py", line 4, in
>
> from setuptools import setup
>
> ImportError: No module named setuptools

This `setup.py` is Buildozer's, not mine.

I uninstalled setuptools completely with `sudo apt-get purge python-setuptools`, `sudo -H pip uninstall setuptools`, and I removed the easy_install command from /usr/local/bin (both `easy_install` and `easy_install-2.7`). I run `sudo easy_install` and it says it's not there. Good.

Then I follow instructions from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-wget), and I run `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python`. It installs successfully, and I test that easy_install is there by doing `sudo easy_install` and checking at `/usr/local/bin`. I also go into the Python shell and type `from setuptools import setup` and it works. So, setuptools is installed. However, `buildozer -v android debug` still fails with the same error.

Could someone figure out what's happening? Setuptools is installed; why is Buildozer not finding it?

This is my log, with log_level = 2 in buildozer.spec: [Link](http://pastebin.com/sq98YuQc)

Comment: Post the full log. Buildozer is running its own python that it built (completely unrelated to your normal system python), but I'm not sure why you'd get a setuptools error from this - either it should not be necessary, or it should be installed by buildozer as a dependency.

Comment: @inclement Check new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old python-for-android toolchain, which does not support a flask backend. Run `buildozer android_new debug` instead to use the new toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out which python binary (environment) does the buildozer use.  My guess that it uses another one then the one you think, and there setuptools isn't installed.

Comment: How would I figure out which binary it uses? What command should I use?

Comment: You can try with strace..  Run: "strace buildozer android debug | grep python" and look for the path it uses to open python interpreter.

Comment: Ah, I found it. It's `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer`, so Python 2.7. I installed Buildozer with `sudo python2.7 setup.py install` so it should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is somewhat hacky, you can first call `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` from your build script, then call `python3 get-pip.py install`, then `python3 -m pip install setuptools`. Just make sure that the python3 you are calling is the one that buildozer uses.

This part of my script looks something like this:

```
hostpython = sh.Command(self.hostpython_location)
os.system("wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py")
shprint(hostpython, "get-pip.py", "install")
shprint(hostpython, "-m", "pip", "install", "setuptools")
```

Reference: a post about the get-pip script: [How to get PIP for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191910/how-to-get-pip-for-python)