# Make python3 to be default version in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to start work with Python on a new Linux server.

I have installed python3 however when I try to do pip install it throws an error saying pip-install error code as below:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-cerbjz/apache-airflow/
```

When I try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` it returns `Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (40.6.3)`

When I do `which python` it returns the below:

```
alias python='python3'
/usr/bin/python3
```

When I open the bashrc file its empty though I had entered the above code in there earlier but it's no longer showing this.

How could I modify this such that the interpreter uses python 3 for all processing.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu or Debian, it should be explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3 For other Linux distributions, it should be similar.

Comment: You may want to use a virtualenv for each of your projects to ensure you're always using the right version of python. More info can be found here: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/.

Comment: Also, you might need to use `pip3`, not `pip`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, when I try pip3 it returns unknown command..

Comment: Then you need to install it.

Comment: did you install python3 correctly?
if you type `python3` or `which python3`, what does it return?

Comment: @Sugimiyantosuma, which python3 returns "/usr/bin/python3"

Comment: check this directory `/usr/bin`, do you find `pip3`

Comment: Use pipenv for each project and forget all problems

Comment: @Sugimiyantosuma could you please advice do I check /usr/bin the folder. From the terminal

Comment: @Sugimiyantosuma, I only see pip in /usr/bin

Comment: @darkhorse Then install pip3

Comment: @aless80 the problem I have is when I do pip3 -V it returns "pip 18.1 from /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)" that's why I am not sure what to do here..

Comment: @darkhorse try to copy /urs/bin/pip to /urs/bin/pip3 and edit it. Notice the python version in the first line of the file (use python3). Maybe not needed but after copying check permissions of the files are the same with ls -l /urs/bin/pip*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and checking @Mulagala's answer here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191910/how-to-get-pip-for-python)

I also suggest getting familiar with how to check python and pip commands and their versions, for example

```
pip -V
pip3 -V  #install it if you do not have it
python --version
python2.7 --version
```