# Installing numpy with virtualenv python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install Numpy on a virtualenv python3.3. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3)

but I eventually get the following error and the installation process terminates:

> `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
>
> `error: Setup script exited with error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-i686-3.3 -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-33m.so" failed with exit status 1`

I also tried `easy_install numpy` and `easy_install-3.3 numpy` with no luck

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Which operative system are you using? Do you have a development version of Python, gcc, and gfortran installed? Which versions?

Comment: Thanks Davidmh for response, I have re-installed my Linux and the problem was solved, but I still can not import numpy from python3.3, I get `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`, although "numpy" folder does exist in "/home/myUser/env3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages" and the output of **which python3.3** is `/home/myUser/env3.3/bin/python3.3` !

Comment: That error does not correspond to a missing import. If I try to import something non existant: `ImportError: No module named 'afasas'`. Can you update your question and post the full traceback, please?

Comment: Thanks Davidmh, the problem is caused by PATH environment variable, the PATH has different value for *root* than my own user! I don't know why, so numpy works well under root but not under other users!