# a error happened while pip was installing scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip3 install scrapy
Collecting scrapy
Using cached Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from scrapy)
Using cached Twisted-17.5.0.tar.bz2
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.9 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.0.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.9->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.9->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.9->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.7->cryptography>=1.9->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Building wheels for collected packages: Twisted
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Twisted ... error
Failed building wheel for Twisted
Running setup.py clean for Twisted
Failed to build Twisted
Installing collected packages: Twisted, PyDispatcher, scrapy
Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
```

---

```
Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py",
line 73, in console_to_str
        return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
line 784, in install
        **kwargs
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
line 878, in install
        spinner=spinner,
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py",
line 676, in call_subprocess
        line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
    File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py",
line 75, in console_to_str
        return s.decode('utf_8')
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install numpy on python3.3 - Install pip for python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3)

Comment: Please check link above, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while installing scrapy. The solution for me was a little bit different, not the file pip_vendor\pkg_resources__init__.py, but the \pip\compat__init__.py, I've changed line 75 to mbcs, and then pip installed scrapy successfully!

After that, I changed that line back to utf-8.