# Python3, how to install numpy on CentOS 7?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, python-3.5, centos7

I'm working with **Python 3.5.1** on a computer having **CentOS Linux** release 7.3.1611 (Core) operating system.

I have to install the `numpy` package.

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3), by running the command:

```
sudo yum -y install python34-setuptools
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libpython3.so from install of python34-libs-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks

**EDIT**: On my machine, I have both Python2.7 and Python3.5, and I want to keep them both

Comment: have you tried `sudo yum install python3-numpy`? Package name might be different but that's how I installed it on Ubuntu via aptitude

Comment: would don't you install it via `pip`?

Comment: @StegSchreck on Linux systems the native package manager is preferred, unless you need to install to a specific project or get a previous version of a package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install numpy on python3.3 - Install pip for python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3)

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, if you maintain multiple python projects on the same developer machine, I would prefer to use python's virtualenv and a requirements.txt for each project. This can then be shipped together with the project, which makes tracking the requirements and their versions a lot easier.

Comment: @Loïc he referenced that question in the comment and specifically said that solution did not help him

Comment: @StegSchreck yeah I know like I said unless you need to install to a specific project. I was just answering your question not trying to argue about they are both valid approaches depending on your needs

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, no worries, I just tried to give more aspects for my comment. Choose whatever suits your case best.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak he did show the command he ran. He didn't follow the nice answer, which is the one with the most upvotes.

Comment: Please follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964956/3322400

Comment: That worked, this question can be closed. Thanks

Comment: I knew it ;) please remember to upvote the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

They should come pre-compiled with Centos OS, so try with:

`sudo yum install numpy scipy`.

So you have two option fist one is installing it system wide, like I mentioned they are pre-compiled with Centos OS, so you can Install the complete `scipy` packages with `numpy` like this:

`sudo yum install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose`

Or you can use pip for the installation, like this:

`python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose`

Please read the official docs from scipy organization on how to [install](https://www.scipy.org/install.html#installing-packages) all the packages on you system.

**NOTE:**

You are right that system wide installation will install it only for `python2.7`, so to use it for `python3.5` you will install via `pip`, so do this:

`sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`sudo python3 -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose`

and I suggest that you install all of this packages, after the installation I've opened my terminal and I've did this:

```
copser@copser-LIFEBOOK-S751:~$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.f2py as myf2py
>>>
```

as you can see I've imported numpy inside `python3.5.2` and it is working, I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04` it should be the same on Centos OS.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I think it installed `numpy` and `scipy` on Python2

Comment: @DavideChicco.it that is correct, so just use `pip` for installation, check out my edited answer.