# pip not working, citing /private/var path failure

Tags: python, pip

In many years of python I have not seen this. When I try to pip install, it complains about `/private/var`. Is this a permissions issue?

location-tools is the name of my python package that I'm trying to install. I am in a virtual environment but I get the exact same error outside of it.

```
    pip install .                                                                                                                             1   master 
Processing /Users/tommy/Development/python-location-tools
Building wheels for collected packages: location-tools
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for location-tools ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvTR-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/tmpm2DqL7pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Requirement already satisfied: gmplot==1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/location_tools
  copying location_tools/__init__.py -> build/lib/location_tools
  copying location_tools/plotting.py -> build/lib/location_tools
  running build_scripts
  creating build/scripts-2.7
  error: file '/private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvTR-build/bin/ll_plot' does not exist

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for location-tools
  Running setup.py clean for location-tools
Failed to build location-tools
Installing collected packages: location-tools
  Running setup.py install for location-tools ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvTR-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-bggTuL-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Requirement already satisfied: gmplot==1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
    Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
    Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
    Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests->gmplot==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/location_tools
    copying location_tools/__init__.py -> build/lib/location_tools
    copying location_tools/plotting.py -> build/lib/location_tools
    running build_scripts
    creating build/scripts-2.7
    error: file '/private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvTR-build/bin/ll_plot' does not exist

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvTR-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-bggTuL-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v9/c461bkzn6r3ctmvg91df94c80000gn/T/pip-ROZvT
```

Comment: Please give some context! What is `location-tools`?

Comment: the name of my python package. I edited my Q

Comment: Looks like your `setup.py` is faulty.

Comment: could you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964956/3322400 ?

Comment: setup looks fine its copied from another dir.

Comment: @Loïc tried that, same issue

Comment: Do you get an error when just building `sdist`? What about `bdist_egg`? Any idea what `ll_plot` is?

Comment: My guess is that your `setup.py` is calling either an entry points script or a binary executable that you have that expects it to be nearby relative to `setup.py` or some other hash-bang line messing things up.

Comment: @daveydave400 that was it! wow tough one. I had a bin script referenced in my scripts section, and in that script, there was no shebang at the top. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this is something wrong in your `setup.py`. Based on the error messages it seems that the `setup.py` script is trying to access a `ll_plot` executable. Since it is saying that it doesn't exist it is likely that you have an entry point script (via setuptools) or are trying to access the binary executable relative to the `setup.py` or other build script.

You'll want to check the shebang on any scripts you have to make sure they aren't trying to use a non-existent environment. Of course if this is a public package (or not too) you'll want to make sure to document the build prerequisites and how the environment needs to be configured to build the package properly.