# no module error when using numpy-1.15.0

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compile a python program where I am using numpy.random.choices(). once I compile I get this one error:

> ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

I read That I have to install numpy package. I did install numpy-1.11.1 it didn't work. I get the same error. I upgraded to numpy-1.15.0 it also didn't work. I used this solution that I found online

> pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed --install-option
>   '--install-data=/usr/local' numpy

and this is the message I get

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.0
.......  $ python3 file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 5, in <module>
import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you _probably_ have both python2 & python3 installed & pip installs numpy for python2 but you are running the file with the python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

you are installing numpy from pip for python 2.x but you are working with python 3.x

to solve your problem download pip3 and download numpy from it.

In the solution below I used `python3.4` as binary, but it's safe to use with any version or binary of python. it works fine on windows too (except the downloading pip with `wget` obviously but just save the file locally and run it with python).

This is great if you have multiple versions of python installed, so you can manage external libraries per python version.

So first, I'd recommend `get-pip.py`, it's great to install pip :

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Then you need to install pip for your version of python, I have `python3.4` so for me this is the command :

```
python3.4 get-pip.py
```

Now pip is installed for `python3.4` and in order to get libraries for `python3.4` one need to call it within this version, like this :

```
python3.4 -m pip
```

So if you want to install numpy you would use :

```
python3.4 -m pip install numpy
```

Note that `numpy` is quite the heavy library. I thought my system was hanging and failing.
But using the verbose option, you can see that the system is fine :

```
python3.4 -m pip install numpy -v
```

> This may tell you that you lack **python.h** but you can easily get it :
>
> On RHEL (Red hat, CentOS, Fedora) it would be something like this :
>
> ```
> yum install python34-devel
> ```
>
> On debian-like (Debian, Ubuntu, Kali, ...) :
>
> ```
> apt-get install python34-dev
> ```
>
> Then rerun this :
>
> ```
> python3.4 -m pip install numpy -v
> ```

from [Loïc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3/33964956#33964956)

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am working on a mac. but I get your Idea. Thank you

Comment: I decided to uninstall numpy and pip to start over with the adequat version. but mac won't let me even with sudo. and I don't want to do it manually-question of damaging the OS. any ways around this?

Comment: what do you mean with "mac won't let me"?

Comment: I wanted to restart the process all over but I guess there is no need for all that. thank you