# pip and python in same path but different version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cloud9-ide, cs50, miniconda

Update:

I've found a temporary solution.

/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/pip install package

However, this still makes no sense to me.
Shouldn't "which pip" and "pip -V" show the same pip?

--

Background:
I use CS50 IDE(Cloud 9 SDK), which comes with python 3.6
After install miniconda, now I have python 3.7
However, my python go to 3.7 correctly but pip stay on 3.6

I've tried to use pyenv, but miniconda was not there.

My Goal is to use jupyter notebook with the same python version with pip.
(which now is python 3.7, instead of pip is installing packages)

```
~/workspace/ (master) $ which pip
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/pip
~/workspace/ (master) $ which python
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python
~/workspace/ (master) $ pip -V
pip 18.1 from /opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
~/workspace/ (master) $ /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
~/workspace/ (master) $ python -V
Python 3.7.0
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443354/install-numpy-on-python3-3-install-pip-for-python3/33964956#33964956

Comment: Take a look in your `$PATH` environment variable. Both `python` and `pip` paths should be the left-most paths in order.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @darthbith /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v9.8.0/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/opt/pyenv/shims:/opt/pyenv/bin:/home/ubuntu/.cs50/bin:/opt/cs50/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin

Comment: I remember I've seen someone's advice to output this on a similar topic, but I have no idea how to work with it.

Comment: Right, so the `/opt/pyenv` stuff is probably the cause of this problem. I'm not sure where those are being added, but check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files and remove those, and you'll probably fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you darthbith.

I used `ls -la ~/ | more` to find `.bashrc` then I removed it.

Now the output is.

```
ubuntu@ikea-tys-ide50-6506503:~/workspace$ which pip
/opt/pyenv/shims/pip
ubuntu@ikea-tys-ide50-6506503:~/workspace$ which python
/opt/pyenv/shims/python
ubuntu@ikea-tys-ide50-6506503:~/workspace$ pip -V
pip 18.1 from /opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
ubuntu@ikea-tys-ide50-6506503:~/workspace$ /opt/pyenv/shims/python -V
Python 3.6.0
```

It seems a bit of ugly, but indeed it worked!

I think there might be a better solution to keep the pretty display, also fix the path.

But I'll say it's solved the core issue.