# Pip failing to install matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, pip

I had to redownload Python and PyCharm due to some issues with my old versions, and am now reinstalling some packages for my project. numpy and pandas installed fine using the PyCharm package manager interface, but when I try to install matplotlib I just get an error with message

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

When I look for more information, PyCharm suggests that I "Try to run `pip install matplotlib` from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at [my path]". When I try to run the command in terminal, I get the following message:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.8 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (93 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.7.1
  Using cached numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.0 MB)
Collecting six>=1.10
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache
  Using cached backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting subprocess32
  Using cached subprocess32-3.5.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (69 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/[myusername]/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (44.1.1)
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, kiwisolver, numpy, cycler, pyparsing, pytz, backports.functools-lru-cache, subprocess32, matplotlib
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.6.1 cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-2.2.5 numpy-1.16.6 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.4 six-1.15.0 subprocess32-3.5.4
```

I'm using windows, but have Ubuntu installed, which I used to try to run that command, since when I try to do anything with pip on git bash I get `bash: /c/Users/[myusername]/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied`.

Anyways, I suppose the problem is that I have Python 2.7 installed (python --version agrees), which won't cooperate with matplotlib. So, I go to /home/[myusername]/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages using Ubuntu terminal and use `rm -r python2.7` to delete folder. Since I have Python 3.9 installed at `C:\Users\[myusername]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe` I assumed that this would just default to the newer version. However, when I restart everything, Python 2.7 just appears again in its old location, and that version continues to run. I believe this has something to do with how I'm using Ubuntu, since Python 2.7 exists only outside my C: drive. But, I'm not sure how to go from here to install matplotlib. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I think that is a network issue

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349800/13552470

Comment: This is a PATH issue. When you installed Python 2.7, odds are it added the filepath to the main python script to your OS's PATH variable. On ubuntu, you can open a terminal and type 'echo $PATH' to view your PATH variable, and find the old Python 2.7 filepath in there. You should be able to just change that line to the path to Python 3.9's main python script, and then pip should work.