# How can i download requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt, requirements.txt

Before i start to telling my problem, my command prompt is not exist. I got
Windows Powershell on Windows 10.

My text is:

```
PyWavelets==0.5.2
opencv-python==3.4.3.18
seaborn==0.8.1
```

And i did that:

```
pip install -r .\requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the s
pelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install -r .\requirements.txt
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What's wrong? Something missed out.

Comment: Clearly pip is not installed. The first step to being a successful programmer is to *read* and *comprehend*.

Comment: Use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`. -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349800 -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed on your machine, it's probably because it's not found in your environment variables and windows doesn't recognize what you are trying to say by 'pip'. You have to tell it where to find it.

To add it to your paths, go to Advanced System Settings in the control panel/ settigs. Then Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > double click the value part, and in a new line enter your pip binary's location (probably C:\Python33\Scripts, but you may have another path).