# Calling `pip uninstall` from the source folder where `setup.py install` was called

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools, uninstallation

If I clone a repos that uses `setuptools`, I can install it using `python3 setup.py install --user`.

For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics
cd pybliometrics
python3 setup.py install --user
```

However, I cannot pip uninstall it anymore. In fact:

```
$ pip3 uninstall pybliometrics
Found existing installation: pybliometrics 3.2.1.dev2
Can't uninstall 'pybliometrics'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I have to change directory for the uninstallation command to be successful. Then change directory back if I want to reinstall it.

Why is that?

How can I uninstall from the same folder that I used to install it?

Here is the output of `pip show` as asked in the comment:

```
$ pip show -f pybliometrics
Name: pybliometrics
Version: 3.2.1.dev2
Summary: Python-based API-Wrapper to access Scopus
Home-page: https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Author: 'John Kitchin and Michael E. Rose
Author-email: Michael.Ernst.Rose@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /run/media/MYNAME/MYID/data/progetti_miei/pybliometrics
Requires: pbr, requests, simplejson, tqdm
Required-by: 
Files:
Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `pip show -f XXX` to the question?

Comment: Maybe the egg info in the local dir prevents `pip` from seeing the installed package - try removing `XXX.egg-info` dir from the project dir, then try uninstalling again.

Comment: @hoefling I have added the output of `pip show`

Comment: @hoefling there is no `egg-info` in the project dir

Comment: `Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt` seems to indicate why it can not be uninstalled. For the installation, you should have used `python -m pip install --user .` instead of `python setup.py install --user`.

Comment: Your commands are inconsistent. You install with `python setup.py` then call `pip show` but use `pip3 uninstall`. Those are all different things. You should always use the `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...`  format: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc thank you very much, I think it goes to the root of the problem. Can you post it as a reply so I can bount you as promised?

Comment: @robertspierre I added my answer, but honestly I am not sure it is THE answer to your question. I do not know what happened that triggered the "Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output of the `pip show -f pybliometrics` command, we can read:

```
Files:
Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt
```

This might explain why it can not be uninstalled. And I am not sure how this happened, nor how to fix it.

But with that said, here are some notes:

1. The commands shown in your question are inconsistent. On one hand you call `pip show -f pybliometrics` and on the other you call `pip3 uninstall pybliometrics`. But `pip` and `pip3` are not necessarily the same thing, and do not necessarily interact with the same projects.
2. Do not use `python setup.py install`. Calling the `setup.py` is now deprecated, the recommended way of installing a Python project is via pip.
3. One should never call the `pip` scripts directly, but should always prefer explicitly calling the *pip* executable module with the targeted Python interpreter (see [this reference article](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349800) for details).

So in your case what you probably should have done (no guarantee it would have solved your issue, but it would have minimized risks):

- Clearly identify which Python interpreter you want to use, let's say it is `path/to/bin/pythonX.Y`
- Install project with: `path/to/bin/pythonX.Y -m pip install --user path/to/pybliometrics`
- Check installed project with `path/to/bin/pythonX.Y -m pip show -f pybliometrics`
- Uninstall project with: `path/to/bin/pythonX.Y -m pip uninstall pybliometrics`

Comment: That was it. I have to install with `path/to/bin/pythonX.Y -m pip install --user path/to/pybliometrics`. Thanks!