# Problems creating a python package using setuptools and trying to install it from local filesystem

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I have created a small package and I'm trying to install it from the local file system but things are not working as expected.

So, let's start with my repository structure

```
python
    packages
        myapiclient
            myapi
                __init__.py
                apiclient.py
            requirements.txt
            setup.py
```

The init file is empty.

**apiclient.py**

```
class APIClient(object):
  pass
```

**setup.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='myapi',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='MyApi API client',
    author='Giuliani D. Sanches',
    author_email='myemail@someprovider.com',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
    install_requires=['requests']
)
```

To install my package using a virtualenv I run the following `pip install` command but it finish with an error:

```
(.vevn) $ pip install --upgrade --no-index --find-links /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/ myapi
Looking in links: /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for myapi
```

Doing a `setup.py install` seems to work:

```
(.venv) $ python3 /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/setup.py install --force
```

**output**

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing myapi.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to myapi.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to myapi.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to myapi.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'myapi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'myapi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying myapi.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying myapi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying myapi.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying myapi.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying myapi.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/myapi-0.1.0-py3.8.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing myapi-0.1.0-py3.8.egg
Copying myapi-0.1.0-py3.8.egg to /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Adding myapi 0.1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myapi-0.1.0-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for myapi==0.1.0
Searching for requests==2.27.1
Best match: requests 2.27.1
Adding requests 2.27.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Searching for idna==3.3
Best match: idna 3.3
Adding idna 3.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Searching for charset-normalizer==2.0.10
Best match: charset-normalizer 2.0.10
Adding charset-normalizer 2.0.10 to easy-install.pth file
Installing normalizer script to /lib-repository/.venv/bin

Using /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Searching for certifi==2021.10.8
Best match: certifi 2021.10.8
Adding certifi 2021.10.8 to easy-install.pth file

Using /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Searching for urllib3==1.26.8
Best match: urllib3 1.26.8
Adding urllib3 1.26.8 to easy-install.pth file

Using /lib-repository/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for myapi==0.1.0
```

```
(.vevn) $ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
build              0.7.0
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.10
idna               3.3
packaging          21.3
pep517             0.12.0
pip                20.0.2
pkg-resources      0.0.0
pyparsing          3.0.6
myapi              0.1.0
requests           2.27.1
setuptools         44.0.0
tomli              2.0.0
urllib3            1.26.8
```

But when I try to import it, I get a ModuleNotFoundError exception:

```
(.venv) $ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapi'
>>>
```

The `pip install` command works just fine after the `setup.py install`

```
(.venv) $ pip install --upgrade --no-index --find-links /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/ myapi
Looking in links: /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/
Requirement already up-to-date: myapi in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myapi-0.1.0-py3.8.egg (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from myapi) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<4,>=2.5; python_version >= "3" in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->myapi) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0; python_version >= "3" in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->myapi) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->myapi) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->myapi) (1.26.8)

(.venv) $
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Quite a different question, but I believe my recommendations can apply here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769733 ... Maybe in your first installation command you should have been more explicit that `myapi` is a local path: `python3 -m pip install path/to/myapi`.

Comment: Yeah, i found what was wrong and posted as an answare. Post your comment as an answer plz, and I will accept it (i didnt' saw your comment before posting).

Answer (score 1):

Well.. after some trial and error, i found a solution:

```
(.venv) $ pip3 install /lib-repository/python/packages/myapiclient/
```

You just need to run the `install` command pointing to the directory containing the `setup.py` file.

No nee to use `--no-index` or `--find-links` in this case.

Now I have everything in place! :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would recommend against calling `pip3`. You should call `python3 -m pip instead`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/