# Python3 pyserial library

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am working on small python scripts. Basically i am not a python programmer and very new to it. Recently i have been working on IOT protocol MQTT. I have installed a open source MQTT clinet based on python3 in my raspberypi board. And now i am facing a problem. I have python 2.7  and 3.2 installed.

My MQTT client work with Python3.x and i want to use pyserial library also which i am not able to , i am getting a error

```
Serial module not found
```

I goggled a bit and end up [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559457/python-no-module-named-serial). Now it say that you need to install pip3 in order to install pyserial for python3.x. 
I tried to install pip3 using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) , but end up installing pip2 using

```
pip install -U pip
```

I feel totally being messed up now. I just want to use pyserial while working with python3.x version.Can any one suggest me how?

Edit 1:

```
 On Linux, Mac OS X and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python commands in combination with the -m switch to run the appropriate copy of pip:

python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

I recently came through this documentation given [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) . But it even give a error to me /usr/bin/python3 : NO module named pip. *main* : 'pip' is a package and cannot be installed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using raspbian on your pi, you could install pip3 from the normal repositories:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

You can get the serial module the same way:

```
apt-get install python3-serial
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded installing pyserial2.7 on a Mac running Yosemite and Python3.4
I entered the `pyserial-x.y` directory and run:
python3 setup.py install

I got lot of errors that I corrected one by one by editing the files containing the syntax errors. Only 2 types of errors are encountered:
- print needs `()`
- except needs `as` instead of `,`

So by correcting the dozen of errors with some patience, installation finish correctly.
I wonder why a syntactically correct version for `Python3` is not ready!