# Ubuntu: pip not working with python3.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, pip

Trying to get pip working on my Ubuntu pc. pip seems to be working for python2.7, but not for others.

Here's the problem:

```
$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg /pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
def get_entry_info(dist, group, name):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
break
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
name = some.module:some.attr [extra1,extra2]
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ python2.7 -m pip //here can be just python, btw
Usage:   
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip <command> [options]
//and so on...

$ python3.4 -m pip
/usr/bin/python3.4: No module named pip
```

From the home/*user*/.pip/pip.log :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'
```

There's no /usr/bin/pip btw.

How can I fix this issue to work with pip and python 3.4 normally?
I am trying to use pycharm, but it's package manager also stucks in this problem.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: what does which  `pip3` output?

Comment: "The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
"

Comment: install  python3-pip as per the message. Do you have a pip-2.7 also?

Comment: great! fixed the issue this way.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd remove the broken `/usr/local/bin/pip`, and also the `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` installation of `setuptools`. Use [python3-setuptools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-setuptools). If you want the latest pip and setuptools, install to your user site-packages (`--user`) or use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have pip installed for python 2, but not python 3.

Ubuntu distributes `python-pip`, `python3-pip`, `python-setuptools` and `python3-setuptools` packages, which you can install (`apt-get install` etc) as necessary. Thereafter, note that `pip` installs for python 2, and `pip3` installs for python 3 (similar to `python`, and `python3`).

*Setuptools* could be said to provide python's "build" process for packages, and *Pip* provides its "install" process. Usually you want both present.

If you want the very latest pip / setuptools, you could always get it from PyPA's bootstrap site:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.4
```

Afterwards you can install the latest setuptools for the appropriate python, e.g

```
$ python{2.7,3.4} -m pip install -U setuptools
```

If you try to install these for the system python, you might need root / `sudo`.

Comment: It's very unsecure to pass something from curl output to python3.4 interpreter.

Comment: @NikolayGolub It's not as if you can't go to the URL and read it first. With HTTPS in place, it's likely not significantly more risky than using a package manager.

Comment: Yes, but it's also a question of trusting to security skills of people behind this site.

Comment: The people who's security skills we are questioning also happen to be the developers of pip, and of PyPI. If you are worried you can use `wget` and read the file beforehand instead of piping it straight to python.

Comment: I am getting some error `Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 523, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip' -> '/tmp/pip-403n951_-uninstall/usr/bin/pip'
`. so I have tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587528/1176331)

Answer (score 14):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

confirm its installation:

```
pip3 --version
```

or

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

now go ahead and install your desired packages (for example `numpy`) using:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Here is the reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux Mint 20.2
I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'`

Answer (score 12):

This worked on my Ubuntu 19.04:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then `pip3` or `python3 -m pip` to install python packages.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when running this command on my raspberry pi

```
python3.4 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

and got this error

```
/usr/bin/python3.4: No module named pip
```

resolved it by installing python3-pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```