# pip, easy_install commands not working in Ubuntu. Python 2.7 and 3.4 are installed

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, python-3.4, easy-install

I'm fairly new to python. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have both python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.0 installed. I was trying to install BeautifulSoup but couldn't because I get an error saying

```
The program 'pip' is currently not installed.
```

I found that it comes bundles with python 3.4. I tried to install pip using `sudo easy_install pip` as mentioned in another question on stackoverflow. But this gives an error `sudo: easy_install: command not found`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` first.

Comment: @ceejayoz This worked. Now I have easy_install and pip. But why do you think pip was not present in the first place? Isn't it supposed to present in python 3.4.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3.4? If you do `python --version`, what does it show?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/ says you'd do `python -m pip install SomePackage` instead of `pip install SomePackage` in 3.4, incidentally.

Comment: `python --version` is showing `Python 2.7.6` and `python3 --version` is showing `Python 3.4.0`

Comment: OK, so `python3 -m pip install SomePackage` for you if you want the package for your Python 3.4 install. `pip install SomePackage` if you want the package installed for your Python 2.7 install.

Comment: You don't have a pip3 command either?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, I didn't. I had to get pip3 using easy_install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip` appears to have turned into `python -m pip` (in your case, `python3 -m pip`, as Ubuntu's keeping the 2.x line available as `python`) in Python 3.4.

`easy_install` for Python 2.7 comes as part of the `python-setuptools` package. Once installed, running `easy_install pip` would install pip for your Python 2.7 installation's use.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. When I tried running `python3 -m pip` I'm getting `/usr/local/bin: No module named pip`. So how do I get pip for python 3.4?

Comment: @ak31 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137291/ubuntu-pip-not-working-with-python3-4 seems to be the same problem, with solution.

Answer (score 4):

How about`apt-get install python-pip`? At least, Debian official repository has [python-pip](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-pip) even from wheezy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, effective as of April 2018, `python-setuptools` no longer ships with `easy_install`, as per Matthias's update:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-i386/python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb.html

However, you can still compile from the source code yourself, and it does work. I just tried it with `sudo easy_install shodan`, and it ran successfully.

```
git clone https://github.com/pypa/setuptools.git
cd ./setuptools
python3 bootstrap.py
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! this saved the day.  python-setuptools indeed no longer ships with easy_instlall but there are so many tutorials/answers out there that say it will work. This saved me so much time. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime, brother.