# Installing pip on windows 8.1(python 3.0.1)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I trying to install python pip on Windows 8.1.
I have `get-pip.py` on my desktop.

In command prompt i use:

```
cd Desktop
python get-pip.py
```

And occur something wrong.

> C:\Users\anonymouse>cd Desktop
>
> C:\Users\anonymouse\Desktop>python get-pip.py
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor__ini
>    t__.py", line 72, in load_module
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor\reque
>    sts__init__.py", line 58, in 
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor\reque
>    sts\utils.py", line 26, in 
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor\reque
>    sts\compat.py", line 56, in 
>    ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor__ini
>    t__.py", line 89, in load_module
>    ImportError: No module named requests
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "get-pip.py", line 17853, in 
>        main()
>      File "get-pip.py", line 152, in main
>        bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
>      File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
>        import pip
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip__init__.py",
>     line 15, in 
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip\vcs\mercurial
>    .py", line 10, in 
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip\download.py",
>     line 32, in 
>      File "c:\users\anonym~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpnd3wja\pip.zip\pip_vendor__ini
>    t__.py", line 92, in load_module
>    ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'

In my PATH environment I have:

```
C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python30;C:\Python30\python.exe;C:\Python30\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python30\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\;C:\Python30\Scripts\;
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is already answered here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=5WVYVeSPKIW17ga92YDoBg&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHlkqM7AmFXNWWWZumcAFoM9e_Rmw get-pip.py isn't supported by python3, us distribute.

Comment: @rfkortekaas: That information in years out of date. `distribute` no longer even exists.

Comment: Sorry I meant setuptools. But the information there is old but still valid!

Comment: @rfkortekaas: No, it's not valid. `get-pip.py` is supported by Python 3.2+. And the whole point of that answer, that `setuptools` doesn't support 3.x, is no longer true. And if you meant that you should install `setuptools` instead of `setuptools`, that doesn't make any sense. Plus you don't need to pre-install `setuptools` anymore anyway, because it's part of `get-pip`.

Comment: Why were you using Python 3.0 in 2015? (Or, really, ever? Even most of the core devs found it too broken to use, and suggested anyone who wasn't interested in actually developing Python itself should wait for 3.1.)

Comment: I'm a newbie in python.. Therefore i downloaded the first link with python... now i will update to python 3.4. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know where you downloaded it from, but if you go to [python.org](https://www.python.org/), the download link there will always have the latest stable versions (3.4.3 and 2.7.9, at present), and, further down, all releases still in support (which goes back to the last few 3.3 and 2.6 versions, at present). Downloading from somewhere else, who knows what you'll get.

Answer (score 2):

As [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#python-os-support) say:

> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and also pypy.

Notice that 3.0 is not included.

In fact, very little works with 3.0. There are many, many things that don't work, or work badly, with 3.0, and there's basically no support for it.

The easy fix here is to upgrade to 3.2 or later—especially if you can upgrade to 3.4, which includes a `pip` bootstrap out of the box.