# Why installing package and module not same in Python?

Tags: python, module, package, biopython

I want to install the Biopython module. So I used the command `sudo apt-get install python-biopython`. That installs the **package**. Now if I type `import Bio` in Python, the compiler cannot find the **module** giving `ImportError: no module named Bio`. Doesn't installing the package imply installing the module?

Comment: did you try import biopython

Comment: @Vignesh `import biopython` also gives the same import error `no module named 'biopython'`

Comment: What python version are you using? Currently `apt-get install` will install the python2 version.

Comment: @Martin I'm using 3.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using 3.4.0

Since you are using Python 3.4 it won't work because the Debian package you install via `apt-get` will only install the Python2.x version.

To install the Python 3 version, I recommend pip. Here how to install (Note that this package *may not* have a Python 3 version):

[How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

**EDIT:**

If you still cannot get the `import` working on python2, try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/pyshared')
import Bio
```

According to [this package's files list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/python-biopython/filelist), the files are installed into a special directory I don't see in the default `sys.path` list