# Django Rest Framework -- no module named rest_framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, django-rest-framework

I've installed django rest framework using `pip install djangorestframework` yet I still get this error when I run "python3 manage.py sycndb":

> ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework'

I'm using python3, is this my issue?

Comment: Have you installed in `settings.py`?

Comment: @BurgerKing I added rest_framework to my installed apps. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you using a virtuel environment?

Comment: I just try to guess reason. May you give your error message?

Comment: @Vingtoft I'm not. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ8NIoLN-yQ at the 5 minute mark.

Comment: @BurgerKing "ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework'" is the error.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You need to install django rest framework using pip3 (pip for python 3):

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
```

Instructions on how to install pip3 can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: I am not sure why but I am still facing the same issue

Comment: This solves my problem. In my case I have done `code`pip install djangorestframework`code` in the windows powershell

Comment: if pip3 does not work, try: python3 -m pip install djangorestframework

Comment: Instead of answers that point out the obvious ("install django, duh") check that you don't have a missing comma in the INSTALLED_APPS list, because that weirdly triggers this ImportError. [Kudos to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033924/3873799).

Comment: @alexlomba87, this error also appears if you use python3 but have installed django using pip for python 2.7, which is why this answer does not point out the obvious for many developers.

Comment: Thank you for adding that, I'd advice to update the answer to add that info, which is not explicit. Pip3 may be the default for many.

Comment: /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 manage.py makemigrations fixed my problem

Answer (score 80):

if you forget `,`,this will happen,it's weird

wrong example: need a `,`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework'
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Glad I scrolled down past trying to reinstall DRF. This solved it for me.

Comment: Such a silly thing xD. It helped me thanks

Comment: I also made this silly mistake. Your solution worked in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Also, check for the possibility of a tiny **typo**:

It's `rest_framework` with an **underscore** (`_`) in between!

Took me a while to figure out that I was using a *dash* instead...

Comment: I agree such a sneaky thing.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning typo. I am using `rest_framwork` instead of `rest_framework`. Missing `e` in `framework`. :)

Comment: And here I am trying to find what sort of dark arts I needed to perform to make this work, and all it was, was a damn typo! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using some sort of virtual environment do this!

1. Exit from your virtual environment.
2. Activate your virtual environment.

After you've done this you can try running your command again and this time it probably won't have any ImportErrors.

Comment: to active your virtual environment, please use `source venv/bin/activate` or `source env/bin/activate` depends on your folder.

Answer (score 6):

if after installing and adding it to your INSTALLED_APPS it persist, then it's most likely because you're using `python3` to run the server and thats okay. So what you do while installing is use `python3 -m pip install djangorestframework` .

Comment: Don't know why python -m as prefix works in virtual env for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you install DRF is for python2, not for python3.

You can use `python console` to check your module:

```
import rest_framework
```

Actually you use `pip` to install module, it will install python2 module.

You should install the pip for python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

So, you can install python3 module.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm getting an error: "apt-get: command not found" when I try to run your command though.

Answer (score 3):

When using a virtual environment like `virtualenv`without having django-rest-framework installed globally you might as well have the error. 
The solution would be:

- activate the environment first with `{{your environment name}}/bin/activate` for Linux or `{{your environment name}}/Scripts/activate` for Windows
- and then run the command again.

Comment: THANK YOU for reminding me! I forgot to activate the VENV for this console!  ARG! (Feeling pretty silly right about now for sure.)  `:facepalm:`

Answer (score 3):

The command which worked for me is

```
python -m pip install djangorestframework
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32569326)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with PyCharm, I found that restarting the program and closing all prompts after adding 'rest_framework' to my `INSTALLED_APPS` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yeh for me it was the python version as well ... 
much better to use pipenv ... 
create a virtual env using using python 3 ...

install pipenv :  `pip3 install pipenv` 
create the virtualenv: `pipenv --python 3` 
activate the virtual env: `pipenv shell`

Answer (score 2):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#apps
'apps.endpoints',
```

]

maybe forgot the comma "," or while pasting packing name it might have extra whitespace "packagename "check for that

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're getting this error while running `docker-compose up`. Make sure to run `docker-compose up --build` because docker needs to install the djangorestframework dependency as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and And solve it with upgrading the pip and install rest_framework after that.(**update everything**)

## Windows Command Prompt

```
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

## Linux Terminal

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

## MacOS Terminal

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

Install Django and Django REST framework

```
pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
```

Answer (score 1):

if you used **pipenv**:

if you installed rest_framework thru the new **pipenv**, 
you need to run it thru the virtual environment:

1.**pipenv shell**

2.(env) now, run your command(for example python manage.py runserver)

Answer (score 1):

First installing the framework globally on the system solved my problem.

```
machine@debian:/$ sudo pip install djangorestframework
or;
root@debian:/# pip install djangorestframework
```

Answer (score 1):

(I would assume that folks using containers know what they're doing, but here's my two cents)

Let's say you setup your project using cookiecutter-django and enabled the docker container support, be sure to update the pip requirements file with `djangorestframework==<x.yy.z>` (or whichever python dependency you're trying to install) and re-build the docker images (local and production).

Comment: Good catch. This was my case. Forgot to re-run pip freeze to update my requirements.txt file which is what the Dockerfile has as dependencies that get installed into the api container.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem, followed these instructions and it worked for me:

1. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (to upgrade pip)
2. `pip3 install djangorestframework`
3. Added `rest_framework` as first app:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'rest_framework',
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       #apps
       'apps.endpoints',
   ]
   ```

Comment: why is it need put first app tell me please?

Answer (score 1):

Install the missing module separately using pip installer

```
pip3 install djangorestframework-jsonapi
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the necessary packages with python3/pip3 inside my virtual environment, it all came down to running my server with `python manage.py runserver` instead of `python3 manage.py runserver`. This was because the virtual environment and other packages were installed using python3/pip3 and not python2/pip2, hence running the server with python3 again resulted in the error. Am sure this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using JWT `pip install djangorestframework-jwt`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my problem was different. I was creating in my bash_profile an alias like:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

And even if I activate my environment, when I ran the command, the python interpreter accessed was from the system and not from my environment.

I just removed the alias from bash_profile and it worked fine.

Comment: Nice work on your first answer, but make sure you format code correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an accepted answer for this question and many other answers also but I just wanted to add an another case which happened with me was Updating the django and django rest framework to the latest versions to make them work properly without any error.

So all you have to do is just uninstall both django and django rest framework using:

`pip uninstall django` `pip uninstall djangorestframework`

and then install it again using:

`pip install django` `pip install djangorestframework`

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed the latest Django 3.1 and Django Rest Framework 3.11.1 libraries only to eventually realize Django 3.1 is not supported by DRF as of 11 April 2020. I did not realize that the exact releases mentioned need to be used.

If you're pulling your hair out because you can't understand why DRF is not importing check these [requirements](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements) and make sure your app is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed it in the virtualenv but forgot to activate the virtualenv while running the command

```
 python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

So in my case I had to just activate the environment and then run the command

```
source [virtualenv folder-name]/bin/activate
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. In my case, I solved it by update Windows Defender configuration.

Answer (score 0):

activate the whole virtual environment

```
cd django_apps
source /root/django-apps/env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pip3 install djangorestframework first
and add rest_framework in the settings.py.
This is how I have a shout out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same language interpreter which you have used in your Django project, which can be an interpreter in the virtual environment, or like me, I have a normal python installed and an anaconda python too. So, try switching the interpreter.
[See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36NUV.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for **MAC or LINUX** as I tried:

1. Open your project path ( where the settings.py is located )
2. Copy the path from the explorer
3. Open your terminal
4. Type cd[space][paste your path location that you copied before]

then try this:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

it's gonna solve.

> REMEMBER: ON **YOUR TERMINAL** OF **MAC** OS OR **LINUX** OS NOT **VsCode**

> point: it also worked for all the other libraries like: **cors-headers**

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, with PowerShell, I had to close and reopen the console and then reactive the virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

To install it, do the following:

```
pip install djangorestframework
pip install markdown     
pip install django-filter
```

We have to check for a few common mistakes:

1. check comma at installed list elements
2. typo errors

Answer (score -2):

[image: rest_framework module]

Try pressing the icon given if you are getting the following error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'"

It will ask you to import the given package, that is `rest_framework` and run the code again.

This worked for me and trying to solve that error for a couple of days.

Comment: Not everyone uses the same editor, and not all editors provide the same feature to import modules through the light bulb.