# PyCharm with matplotlib Problems

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

I try to run Matplotlib [Tutorial 1 - Introduction and Line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7Bo_J8x_dw&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfefDfXb9Yf0la1fPDKluPF&index=1&feature=iv&src_vid=wAwQ-noyB98&annotation_id=annotation_2821107469) on sentdex.

What I did, I went in File/ Settings/ Project Interpreter to add the library matplotlib throug Pucharm:

I click on Install Package

```
matplotlib
Description: plotting package
Version: 1.5.1
Author: John D. Hunter
```

I got :

```
Error occurred when installing package 'matplolib'
Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found

Executed command :
pip install matplotlib

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the
correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at
'/usr/bin/python3.5'.

Error: Python packaging tool 'pip' not found
```

I don't know how to fix that

Comment: You have to install pip, a package management tool for python. 
See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Answer (score -1):

try to install matplotlib from cmd windows:

1. start --> cmd.exe
2. go to the directory that your python is installed.
3. type dir to see the list of the directories. you should have directory called 'scripts'.
4. type: `cd scriptes` (to move to the scripts directory)
5. type again `dir` - the pip is in scripts directory
6. now type: `pip install matplotlib`