# Can't install anything with pip

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation, pip

I can't install Beautifulsoup by running:

```
pip install Beautifulsoup
```

The output was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3080, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3066, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3093, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 952, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

What is the exact problem and what should I do?

Comment: First update your pip: `pip install --upgrade pip` or `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: with the first one, the output was the same error but with the second command, the output was `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`.

Comment: The answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3