# Python script can't find pymongo module - Mac

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

so I was trying to run a python code, but the shell kept telling me that no 'pymongo' module was found.
Now, I have python 3.5.1 installed.
when I run pip freeze | grep pymongo it returns pymongo == 3.2.2 so it's clearly installed. I tried to run pymongo from the shell rather than a script but I get the same error every time.

> > > import pymongo
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'

So, help? It worked fine a month ago or so..

Answer (score 1):

It means `PyMonogo` module is not installed for your Python 3. In the shell you can check the installed modules for your python.

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

Check if `pymongo` is listed there. You have to install `pymongo` for python 3.

Comment: Install pip for python3. Take look at this: [How to install pip with Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3). Then install pymongo.