# Raspberry Pi 3 - OpenCV and Picamera

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project with some friends and we're facing a bit of a problem with our implementation of `picamera`.

We're trying to import `cv2` and `picamera` at the start of the program (working with Python 3) and so far importing `cv2` works just fine.
When we're trying to import picamera it tells us this: `ImportError: No module named picamera`.

I made sure we installed `picamera` with "`sudo apt-get install python-picamera`" and with "`...python3-picamera`" and it tells me the modules are installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Our goal is to take a photo every 0.5s and use it for our OpenCV-program, and we wanted to do that with `picamera`, and only that.

Might the problem be that our project is located on the Desktop and not in some kind of Project folder or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have a look on the latest two posts here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/

Comment: The Python dependencies that are installed by the script don't get installed with `sudo`. You could do `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip`
`$ sudo pip install picamera` instead.

Comment: @NickilMaveli thanks for trying to help, doesn't work still. It says everything is already downloaded, 0 downloaded,0 changed. The usual stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was posted a while ago, but for those who are experiencing the same issue, try this:

```
pip install "picamera[array]"
```

According to [piimagesearch.com](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) it's necessary to install the optional "array" sub-module for openCV to interface properly with picamera.

Answer (score 0):

This should might help

```
sudo pip3 install picamera
```

I ran this on my desktop and something installed so it should work

if pip isn't installed you may have to run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

sources:

[How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)