# How can I use pip to pip install Python 3 in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, cloud9-ide

Currently using `Cloud9`'s ACE IDE dev environment for some learning opportunities, however, I ran into an API that is exclusively made for `Python 3`.

How can I pip install Python 3 while keeping python `2.7.6` (the current version) intact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: I am 90% sure that it is not possible to install Python using PIP.

Comment: You realise you cannot use the lib with your python2 code? Also as david pointed out you 100 percent cannot install python with pip, if you want difference versions of python use a virtualenv

Comment: That is a horrible dupe target. Literally nothing to do with this question except it mentions a few of the same words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `pip` to install Python 3. In any case, since you specifically mentioned the Cloud9 IDE, it already comes with both Python 2 and 3. `python` is symlinked to `python2` though, so if you want to call Python 3, you have to type `python3` (instead of just `python`) in the terminal.

Comment: I didn't know Cloud9 had both active. That solves my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`pip` cannot be used to install `Python`, `pip` is used to install python packages, it's a *package manager*.

If you are looking for a command line utility that handles installing different version of `CPython`, (among other things) you can look at [`conda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/), conda is an *environment manager*.

`conda` is usually packaged with [`anaconda`](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index) and works by managing environments in which you can specify different versions of Python. It helps you easily install different (with `conda env create` versions of python and switch between them via different environments (with `source activate`).

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems like you want to use apt-get instead of pip.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```