# How to make print something in columns?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a yahtzee, and I have problem with my printing, I need to get what I'm supposed to print into nice looking columns: I want it to look something like this:

```
Name     Joakim     Anders
Bonus    0          0
Ones     0          0
Twos     1          1
```

Is there a way to make it look like this (with nice columns)? I found another thread about this but it was pretty old and I'm using python3 currently.

Answer (score -1):

[terminaltables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables) might suit your needs.

Comment: Im trying to install it with the command in your link, but it says "pip program not installed, you can install it by typing "sudo apt-get install python-pip". When I type that, it says I need a password, but I cannot type anything...

Comment: You can type something, but no characters will appear. If you type your password and press <enter>, pip should be installed.

Comment: also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6587528/517560

Comment: That's great, thank you, I'm using a virtual machine (ubuntu) on my windows computer, if I interpret him right, I should go with my package manager, but how do you do that? It sounds like everyone should know about that, but I dont...

Comment: It's pretty weird, because something started that seem'd like it was the right thing, a lot of things started to download, for example:
Setting up python pip.....
Setting up ´...
But when it's about to finalize, it says that something is wrong with my internet (It's not, I have internet on both the windows and the ubuntu system)

Comment: So many questions ;). Try to take small steps and read documentation.

Comment: ye, you're right, so frustrating to not get anywhere. thats why I ask so much..

Comment: Jieter, hahaha, sorry for asking again, but I think pip is installed (they say it is at least, even though I got some small error message). I try to install terminaltables, I get errormessage ("could not create usr/local/lib...., permission denied). Anyone else recognizing this ?