# Unable to import boto3 library after installation

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto3

I installed boto3 library from AWS SDK but when I try to import in python interpreter, I get error. Here is the traceback:

> > > import boto3
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/rahul/rahul/boto3/boto3/**init**.py", line 16, in 
> > >           from boto3.session import Session
> > >         File "/home/rahul/rahul/boto3/boto3/session.py", line 17, in 
> > >           import botocore.session
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'botocore'

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in installation. It is compatible in python 2.7 but not for 3.4 version as it is working for 2.7 but not for 3.4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3 might be of interest

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have installed boto3 but not botocore

botocore is the basis of boto3 but is lower level

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/botocore

Comment: Actually, I was trying to run in Python 3.4
but I figured out it was giving error in Python 3.4 but not in python 2.7 so it might be a compatibility issue.