# Installing module beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, module, pycharm

my problem is  with installing module "beautifulsoup4". In pycharm i installed the package correctly but when im trying to import the module it says no module found with that name.and i searched the internet for solution and i found a  way for that .
It says in terminal use this command :

"pip install beautifulsoup4 "

But still pycharm or id le shell cant find the module.even i tried the command :

"pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade"

and terminal says its already up-to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your version of python selected in pycharm and the version of python you installed BeautifulSoup

If using python3

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup
```

or

```
pip3 install bs4
```

in case of python2 replace pip3 with pip

try to change python interpreter in pycharm settings.

alternatively try ( only for Ubuntu and Like Linux)
I can't remember the exact package.
try

```
apt-get install python3-bs4
```

or

```
apt-get python3-BeautifulSoup
```

again do it with python if you want for python2

Answer (score 2):

use pip3:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: It says: "requirment already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages"

Comment: @babakabadkheir whats your pycharm python interpreter? 3.4 or 3.5 or ...?

Comment: Python is 3.5.2 and pycharm version is pycharm 2016.2.1

Comment: @babakabadkheir use `python3.5 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: It says no module named pip

Comment: @babakabadkheir hmmm, whats your linux distribution? i tested it in ubuntu14.04:)

Comment: Linux version 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 debian kernel (debian 5.3.1-5) .

Comment: @babakabadkheir sorry,i dont know:) possible answers: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: @babakabadkheir hey, hope [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) work for you:)