# Python version conflicts and pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

It is a tough situation I am dealing with. Here is short version of my problem:

- I am working on Ubuntu 12.04
- I would like to install `Python 3.5.x` with `openCV` library. I would also like to use `pip3` for managing package installation of python.

**Here is how the version of my pythons looks like**

```
    $ python --version
      Python 2.7.3
    $ python3 --version
      Python 3.5.2
```

So far it looks I have achieved my goal.

**When I use `virtualenv` to  manage `python3` libraries:**

```
   virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
   source py3env/bin/activate
```

I see the version of my python as follows:

```
   (py3env)yxxxxa@yxxxxa-Precision-M4800:~$ python3 --version
    Python 3.2.3
```

I seems there is another version of python in my machine `3.2.3` messing up with the version `3.5.2` that I have installed. This is my first problem.

**The second related problem is that I am unable to install `pip 3`. There is this error I receive due to the same python version conflict:**

```
 $ pip
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor /pkg_resources/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
  warnings.warn(msg)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
 load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in  load_entry_point
 return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
 return ep.load()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
  entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
   from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
   from pip.download import path_to_url
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
   from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
   from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, IncrementalBar
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
empty_fill = u'∙'
                  ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   yasharatena@yasharatena-Precision-M4800:~$ pip3
  /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
   warnings.warn(msg)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
   return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in  load_entry_point
   return ep.load()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
   entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, IncrementalBar
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
    empty_fill = u'∙'
                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What are your expert opinions about the stated problem? Any cool idea to handle this? Thanks alot in advance

Comment: is `which python3` different that `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: The result of `$which python3` is: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: So there is your answer. You're creating virtualenv from different binary. `/usr/bin/python3 --version` is 3.2.3., `/usr/local/bin/python3 --version` is 3.5.2.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my first problem. Now the second problem aslo remains, how can I install pip3 under python 3.5.2 (preferably using viretualenv) ?

Answer (score 1):

> This solved my first problem. Now the second problem aslo remains, how
>   can I install pip3 under python 3.5.2 (preferably using viretualenv) ?

Here is answer:

```
python3 -m virtualenv py3env

source py3env/bin/activate
```

Python 3.5 should have pip by default, also after above commands You can use pip:)

For example :

```
python -m pip install requests
```

EDIT:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3) You could find very good explainations if You still need install pip after create virtualenv.