# Try to install pymodbus3 but can't find Python 3.0 or later

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pymodbus3

I have installed Python 2.7, 3.5.2 and 3.6. I try to install `pymodbus3` for Python 3.5.2. When I run

```
pip install -U pymodbus3 --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

I get the error:

```
 Collecting pymodbus3
 Downloading pymodbus3-1.0.0.tar.gz (80kB)
 100% |################################| 81kB 6.8MB/s
 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
 You need python 3.0 or later to run this script!
```

I also added Python 3.5.2 to the Python path.
What is the next step for analyse my problem?

EDIT:

```
pip --version
```

gives me

```
pip 9.0.1 from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

So I assume that I have to use pip for python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install -U pymodbus3 --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

`pip` is for Python 2 and `pip3` for Python 3.

You can find out where `pip` is located with.

On Windows:

```
where pip
```

or

```
where pip3
```

on Unix/Mac:

```
which pip
```

or:

```
which pip3
```

The argument `-a` shows you all instances. You can choose one explicitly:

```
/path/to/my/pip/pip3
```

On Windows the path might not be set.

```
where python
```

should give you the Python executable.

In the same directory should be a sub-directory `Scripts` that contains `pip3`.
Add this to your `PATH`.

You can try first with an absolute path:

```
C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3
```

Comment: how to install pip3 on windows?

Comment: If you have Python 3, you should also have `pip3`.

Comment: `where pip3` couldn't find anything. Is there a problem with my path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: I opened a question (How to install pip3 on windows): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows. The link before was only helpful when using Linux