# How to install pip3 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

I use python 2.7, 3.5.2 and 3.6. Normally `pip3` is installed with python3.x. But ...

The code:

```
where pip3
```

gives me:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should check this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: @m4nzm333 you should read the title, "windows"

Answer (score 108, accepted):

On Windows `pip3` should be in the `Scripts` path of your Python installation:

```
C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3
```

Use:

```
where python
```

to find out where your Python executable(s) is/are located. The result should look like this:

```
C:\path\to\python\python.exe
```

or:

```
C:\path\to\python\python3.exe
```

You can check if `pip3` works with this absolute path:

```
C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3
```

if yes, add `C:\path\to\python\Scripts` to your environmental variable `PATH` .

Comment: My /Scripts-folder of python3.5.2 and python3.6 are empty. Also after repairing python they are empty. Thanks for your help"

Comment: Try a global search for `pip`/ `pip3`on your hard drive. Maybe they are somewhere else.

Comment: Uninstalling and installing helped me! I found pip3 in the scripts-folder. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What if it is not there? it seems there is not pip3 in win-64 channels as of 6/23/17.

Comment: "win-64 channels" sounds like you are using conda/anaconda. Then the name is just `pip`.

Comment: what does it mean if where python and where python3 both return nothing, but i can run base .py scripts from both?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 8):

I Installed pip and pip3 in my windows 10 system easily from the official Microsoft store.

**Search python3.9 in Microsoft store**. then, click on "Get" to install on you windows platform.

It will install all python install packagers like PIP, PIP3.

Answer (score 2):

For python3.5.3, pip3 is also installed when you install python. When you install it you may not select the add to path. Then you can find where the pip3 located and add it to path manually.

Answer (score 2):

By default installer from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) adds this PATH variable:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`
but `pip3` installs to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`.

You should add this path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` to your `PATH` variables.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it is preferable to use the py launcher for managing multiple Python versions.

Please use `py -m pip`. You may specify the Python version using `-3` or `-3.6`.

For more options see the help with `-h`.

Answer (score -1):

It is not require that pip installs in python 2.7; if python2 is missing, pip will install in python3. The above statement was if you have both versions of python installed.

If you’re using Linux, you may verify which pip is installed with the ‘which’ command. As an example,

```bash
which pip
```

If you type this command into the Linux terminal, it will show you the pip and python versions that are installed. Otherwise, if you haven’t installed pip, you can get an error.

To check the pip3 version on Linux run the following command:

```bash
which pip3
```

If you type this command into the Linux terminal, you will see about the pip3 and python versions that are installed. Otherwise, if you haven’t installed pip3, you might get an error.

Answer (score -2):

There is another way to install the pip3: just reinstall 3.6.