# how avoid Anaconda to hijack pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-3.6

I have 2 versions of Python installed on my PC (Windows 7, 64Bit). 
Python 2.7 Version installed with Anaconda
Python 3.6 Version installed directly from python.org (the "regular IDLE")

Now, i would like to install the necessary packages on the 3.6 using pip, but anaconda keeps on hijacking the command.

For example, on typing in the cmd window:

> pip install numpy

and i get:

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
>   c:\users\georges\anaconda2\lib\site_packages

Which is the case for python2.7, but i was trying to install it for version 3.6 installed without Anaconda. 
I tried re-installing pip hoping it would erase the hijacking by Anaconda2 ... failed.
I am contemplating to remove Anaconda2 altogether although i risk that in windows, removing a programme does not necessaraly remove the dependencies.

Any lead please ?

Comment: Just set the correct paths. It might even be enough to call pip3. But this problem is more or less a OS-usage problem.

Comment: @sascha you still the words from my mind (keyboard :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `pip3` install pip3 and you should be able install packages for python3

It should come as standard with python3 installation setup.

First check if it is there with

```
where pip3
```

For any further issues check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows)

You don't need to uninstall anaconda2. Both python versions can co-exist and libraries different managed by different package installers pip for python 2 and pip3 for python 3 respectively.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Install it with pip3, because you want it for python 3:

```
pip3 install numpy
```