# Changing which Python version pip points to

Tags: python, pip

I am using python2.7 and python3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. After upgrading pip to v10 I am no longer able to install packages for python2.7 using pip.

How can I change pip to point to python2.7?

```
$ pip -V
pip 10.0.0 from /home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

$ pip3 -V
pip 10.0.0 from /home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2

$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

$ python3 -m pip install some_module
$ python -m pip install some_module
```

`python/python3 -m pip install some_module` both installs to python 3.5.

Using Anaconda is not an option.

Comment: Did you check if there is now a `pip2`?

Comment: There is no pip2. 'The program 'pip2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install python-pip.'

Comment: Potentially you can create that link yourself: `sudo ln -s /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2`.

Comment: Both your `pip` and `pip3` points to the same binary. You need to find `pip` (v2.7) exists and fix it using $PATH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python3.6-venv hijacks pip. what is a way to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871761/python3-6-venv-hijacks-pip-what-is-a-way-to-prevent-this)

Answer (score 6):

Had a very similar problem. Forced re-installation of pip caused pip to point back to python 2.7

```
sudo python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system, I have a `pip2` which points to the python you're looking for.  For clarity, I just stopped using `pip` and only ever use `pip2` or `pip3`.  Not sure if this was a thing back when this question was asked, but looks to be the general solution now.

`pip3 -V`

pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

`pip2 -V`

pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pip is not pointing to the correct python version. I tried installing python-pip package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then, pip2 and pip2.7 came out available in my terminal again:

```
$pip [press tab tab]
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.5
```

Now I upgraded pip2 with:

```
$pip2 install --upgrade pip
$pip2 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Currently with version 20.0.2 of pip2, that is now pointing to python2.7, it's available to install any package into the specific version we need.

Answer (score -1):

In my case `python` points to 2.7 while `py` works to 3.6. You can check this by typing `py` in Terminal, and if so then

```
py -m pip install something
```

Comment: `py` doesn't work in an OS that has `/usr/bin/python` (Ubuntu).