# tdryer/hangups installing on windows

Tags: python, windows, github

I've installed [hangups project](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups) using both pip and setup.py on the source code.
In the [documentation](https://hangups.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) it **clearly** says an executable/command should be created called "`hangups`", but none can be found.

I'm sure it's not a major problem just me missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [installation page](https://hangups.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), pip, for instance, should get the hangups executable.

```
pip3 install hangups
```

As illustrated by this other issue, the end result should be in `~/.local/bin`.
But on Windows, that would be at `C:\Python36-x64\Scripts\`.

Comment: Well, first of all - thanks for answering!
Second of all, there is no pip3 command (nor C:\Python36-x64 directory).
I DID find the directory under appdata in my user directory... where I did find the hangups executable!

So thanks, but care to explain why those difference exist on my machine?

Comment: @user2554457 Do you have installed Python3 64bits? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41501815/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21182892/6309)

Comment: I have it installed, I'll add the scripts under Python to the PATH environment variable. I mistakenly thought it adds it on installation.

p.s: If I have more questions about the hangups, should I open a new question or edit my current?

Comment: @user2554457 it is better to open a new one, to keep the questions separate.