# Why is a package I have installed not getting recognised

Tags: python, bots, discord

I have installed a package named hypixel for my discord bot using `pip install hypixel`. It finished installing without any errors. At the top of my script I have `import hypixel`. But when I try and run it I get this error:

```
File "D:\Documents\Discord Bot\Addicts Discord Bot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import hypixel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypixel'
```

I am not sure if this is too relevant but my pip isn't the latest version and I get an error when I try and update it.

Edit: I have now successfully updated my pip. But even when I try and reinstall the package it still won't work.

Comment: Try upgrade pip to latest version with `pip install --upgrade pip` then to install the package, `pip install hypixel`

Comment: Do you have both python and python3 installed?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **pip install python**, use **pip install hypixel**. Then try to import it in your code using **import hypixel**.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say you used `pip install python`, did you mean to say `pip install hypixel`?

Also if you use python3 but have python3 installed make sure you use `pip3`.

You can install this with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` (assuming you use a debian based distro). Then use `sudo pip3 install hypixel`

Edit:

For windows installation follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows)

Comment: I did mean to say `pip install hypixel`. Also, I am using windows so I don't think I can do `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.