# Issue with tensorflow-mkl on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am new to tensorflow. In fact using it because the server code I am writing calls that.

I am using conda to setup the various packages. I did conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-mkl. (Note: I dont have a GPU - using a CPU)
I always get this error:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
```

The specific line of code where this happens:

```
tensorflow.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(path)
```

On further research, I figured out that this is because the tensorflow package I have does not support this above instruction and needs to have support for the same.

Some questions:
1. How do we ensure the tensorflow package I have does support the above function? Any source from which I can download?

2. If it is not important, is there a way to suppress this instruction or any errors from it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conda or pip installations to download the  tensorflow that supports cpu. You can use the following commands from your terminal

```
conda install tensorflow -c anaconda
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

You can use this link if you havent installed pip yet

[How to install pip3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows)

Hope this helps..

Comment: I did this already. Does not work. Both conda install as well as pip install tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX

This is just a warning.Not an error.

To suppress this warning please add the following lines before your actual code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

As per the [tensorflow official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3),starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs.

You can refer the below url for more details on Intel Optimized tensorflow installation:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide

Hope this answer your query.Thank you.