# Can you please give me solution for installation of pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x

everyone's saying thatr pip comes pre-installed on python 3.4 and later versions... but i can't find them anywhere when i have python 3.7.8 and already installed it to path!
even when i tried to install pip through get-pip.py , it returned me this error message

```
C:\Users\Susanta>cd C:\Programs\Python37

C:\Programs\Python37>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23484, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_internal\co
mmands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cl
i\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_internal\in
dex\package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_internal\in
dex\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requ
ests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requ
ests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requ
ests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Susanta\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppz390nc1\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requ
ests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

C:\Programs\Python37>
```

Can anyone help me out... I'm actually learning python and really want to install external modules but unable to because of this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pip3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows)

Comment: After installing Python, you should have a `pip.exe` in the `python3\Scripts` directory. Also, on my system with Python 3.8.3 installed, the script to get it is called `get-pip-py3.py`.

Comment: I'm not having that.... I've tried reinstalling nothing works....

Answer (score -1):

This is my automated install script for setting up a local virtual environment from an `requirements.in` file. It has had some limited cross-platform testing:

- https://github.com/JamesMcGuigan/requirements.sh/blob/master/requirements.sh

Comment: What can it help me with? Can I know?

Comment: It will automate creating a local venv directory to create a virtual environment and installing all your dependencies

Comment: but i'm using windows 7 32 bit ..... ithink its bash file...do u have anything else