# I see pip in the python/python39/scripts folder but it still says "pip command not found"

Tags: pip

I tried pip3, it still doesn't do anything. I tried to reinstall it from reinstalling python or installing it in idle, but if i try to do "python get-pip.py" it just goes to another line, it doesnt do anything. im on windows btw
Edit: I followed what the commenter said, and if i type "py -m pip install" it lets me install a package so tysm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding pip to environment variables .  [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41501815/12250600)

On Windows pip3 should be in the Scripts path of your Python installation:

`C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3`

Use:

`where python`

to find out where your Python executable(s) is/are located. The result should look like this:

`C:\path\to\python\python.exe`

or:

`C:\path\to\python\python3.exe`

You can check if pip3 works with this absolute path:

`C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3`

if yes, add C:\path\to\python\Scripts to your environmental variable PATH

Comment: I'm sorry, but im really new to programming, how do i check if it works and what is enviroment variable path

Comment: i hope [this](https://telegra.ph/-10-13-210) will help you @SourPickle0402