# Issues installing pip for python 3.8 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

Im  trying to install numpy using pip on windows 10 but i keep getting the same error, even though they added it to the path. Any help please because i need to get this to work for an assignment i have to hand in but i cant start it without fixing this first[image]

Comment: Is pip realy in your PATH? Try first `where pip`

Comment: Try looking at this solution. I think it solves your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41501815/13337212

Comment: i had a look but my problem is that when I installed python, i never got a scripts folder containing pip. However, I was also asked to install anaconda as i first started programming python using Jupiter notebook and pip is installed and contained in an anaconda folder however, I also needed to install python to run on cmd, but pip wasn't installed along with python

Comment: @Käseknacker I entered the command and i got an error:   INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: currently all Pythons should have `pip` preinstalled but in older versions you had to download script [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) - and you can try to use this script.

Comment: @furas i did use the script but it told me to supress another pip

Comment: little off topic: why your folder has name `embed`? Where did you get this Python? Maybe you installed some strange version and it has problem. Did you download it from [python.org](https://www.python.org/). If you plan to work with Science modules then you may try [Anacond](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) which gives Python + precompiled some modules. Normally some modules may need C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the resource here: [Pip Not Recognized Windows](https://www.getdroidtips.com/fix-pip-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/#:~:text=%20How%20to%20Fix%20PIP%20Not%20Recognized%20As,pip%20is%20included%20in%20Python%20Installer%20More)

> 1. Open `cmd` (`Windows Key + R`, type `cmd`)
> 2. In `cmd`, type `echo %PATH%`
> 3. Find path to: `C:\Python37\Scripts`
> 4. Using that path, type `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python37\Scripts"`
> 5. Afterwards, type `python -m pip install numpy` to install numpy

Let me know if this helps

Comment: i tried this and i got no errors except for the last step, i got: No module named pip

Comment: @Nicole Could you try `python get-pip.py` before trying the last step again? Let me know how it goes