# pip3 in ubuntu 14.04 alongside pip for 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to install pip3 for my python3 environment, but am finding it is not recognized by system, despite being installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

OK, so it should be installed:

```
$ pip3
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

But, but, I just did that!

Here are my pythons:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6

$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.3
```

What's happening?  Can't tell whether this is a pip or apt-get issue.  My .bashrc and similar are also clean of anything that would be aliasing pip3 in an unusual way.

Comment: Try just closing and reopening terminal then check it again.

Comment: Same result, unfortunately!

Comment: Try the manual way from this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: Minimum diagnostic that is needed: `which python python3 pip pip3`. You can also try this other method to use pip3: `python3 -m pip`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that pip3 is found in one of the directories that are specified in $PATH.
On my machine:

`$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3`