# what is the Correct get-pip.py for python 3.1.1 for windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip on python 3.1.1 but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in
>   
>       main()   File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
>       bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)   File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
>       import pip   File "c:\users\akisho~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpofqojo\pip.zip\pip__init__.py",
>   line 21, in    File
>   "c:\users\akisho~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpofqojo\pip.zip\pip_vendor\reque
>   sts__init__.py", line 66, in    File
>   "c:\users\akisho~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpofqojo\pip.zip\pip_vendor\reque
>   sts\models.py", line 856
>       http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, rea son, self.url)
>                                                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need to install python setup tools in order to have pip you can download it from here. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: please go through link
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3> you will find your answer.